# How to create a custom popup window in XAF DevExpress adding my own UI elements?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I have a C# XAF application up and running and I added a Websocket connection, the connection was successful but now I need to add action button that when I click it will open a customized window for me with a textbox and a send button. whenever i click send it will send the textbox data back to the server.
the textbox and the button are not related to any business object. just simple textbox and send button to communicate with the websocket server.

is it possible? i tried to add my custom UI but with no success.

I tried adding a customized controller but at the end u got stuck that this controller should be bound to a business object.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in Winforms XAF, if that is what you want you can simply add
Form Form1 = new Form1();
Form1.ShowDialog();

In your action execute function.

I don't know about Blazor/ASP.Net Webforms, but it should be the same type.

Another way to go is to make custom editors and utilize these in your popupwindow.